# Object can not be set ERROR

Tags: objective-c

Just have a quick question, event.header is type String , I need to set the object but I'm unsure what I have to set it to? it's set to String ?

I'm getting this error  "object can not be set"

```
event.header = [values objectAtIndex:0];
event.longitude = [[values objectAtIndex:2] floatValue];
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you make a @property to define a setter for it?

Comment: Tbh im not sure , im a newbie

Answer (score 0):

You have to much brackets in your first line. Try it like this:

```
event.header = [values objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Yeah sorry that was a typo in my question ,  event.header = [values objectAtIndex:0]; doesn't work